# Removal of OnClickListener and automation

Tags: android

I would like to remove the button and have the process automated in the following code. I have looked around but haven't quite came across the answer I need.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText Number1;
EditText Number2;
Button calc;
TextView output;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number1);
    Number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number2);
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
}

public void doCalc (View view) {
    double intNum1 = Double.parseDouble(Number1.getText().toString());
    double intNum2 = Double.parseDouble(Number2.getText().toString());
    double mOutput = (intNum1*intNum2);
    output.setText("Output" + mOutput);
}
```

}

I am quite new to java having mostly done some perl scripting so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Automated how? When the button gets pressed doCalc() takes numbers and prints out their sum. So, this printing shall happen automatically when?

Comment: I would like to remove the button completely, no pressing of a button, when Number1 and Number2 is populated doCalc is called.

Comment: Then you have to set up onTextChangedListener() for both edit boxes and do calc when text changed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the button, then you have to watch the text fields being changed, with a TextWatcher.
Something like this:

```
        TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {                   
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {                          
                double d = Double.parseDouble(Number1.getText()) * Double.parseDouble(Number2.getText());
                result.setText(d + "");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

        });
Number1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
Number2.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Sorry for any bugs, I mostly copy/pasted quickly, good luck.